# Gostaria de criar um objeto igual a uma consulto no banco de dados

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Gostaria de criar um objeto com os campos iguais a da consulta do ActiveRecord, porém, com os campos pré-preenchidos ou em branco, para que sejam chamados da mesma forma no outro arquivo...

Para exemplificar melhor, o trecho de código que eu

```rb
      def organization_name_for_emails(organization = @organization)
        @organization_name_for_emails ||= organization.emails.first
        if @organization_name_for_emails == "" || @organization_name_for_emails.blank?
          #CRIAR O OBJETO
          return @organization_name_for_emails = "RETORNO QUE EU 
QUISER DAR DA TABELA, NESTE CASO GOSTARIA DE DAR UM VALOR 
chamado "Nome" para o campo "name" da tabela que irá receber no outro arquivo."
        else
          return @organization_name_for_emails
        end
      end
```

Neste caso ele teria que funcionar neste trecho de código,

```rb
  def confirm_email(event, participant)
    @event = event
    @organization = event.owner_organization
    @participant = participant
    **@organization_name_for_emails = organization_name_for_emails(@organization)
    subject = I18n.t("views.mailer.event_registration.confirm_email.subject", :name_subject => @organization_name_for_emails.name)**
    destination = AppConfig[:send_emails] ? @participant.email : AppConfig["default_email"]
    mail(:to => destination, :subject => subject)
  end
```

Será que alguém já passou por isso, tem uma solução melhor ou alguma dica?

Obrigado!

Comment: Eu não consegui entender muito bem o que você quer. =\

Comment: Então, eu resolvi o problema de outro modo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pessoal obrigado por quem se dispôs a ajudar, arrumei o problema de outra maneira, utilizei um array e peguei a resposta por array, deu tudo certo.

```html
  def options_to_send_email
    @email_default ||= self.emails.first
    if @email_default.present?
      [@email_default.email, @email_default.name.present? ? @email_default.name : 'APP']
    else
      [AppConfig[:from_email], 'APP']
    end
  end
```

E para pegar a informação utilizei a seguinte opção.

```html
email, name  = @organization.options_to_send_email
```

Dessa forma, não precisei criar objeto para a resposta que precisava...